# PvT - How and When to Get High Templar

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

OK, I am currently rank 2 or 3 in my Silver league, and am starting to face more and more Gold leaguers. I play Protoss, I consider my macro good (certainly room for imporvement, but my macro is almost always better or equal to my opponents unless I am micro-ing), and my big "problem matchup" is PvT. I prefer to go High Templar over Colossi against Terran, but I'm not really certain at what point I should be getting it, and how to integrate them with 1-1 ups and a general army. So when should I get Templar? After 2nd is saturated? After 3rd? And what should I get before that? How would I counter a stim timing push? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

There are a hundred possible answers to this question. As a rule of thumb you want Colossi first since you can get them a lot faster and you really, really need them against marines and marauders. Without any sort of AoE on your side, Terrans MMM can beat a Protoss army cost efficiently.

Once the opponent is building Vikings, slowly transition into High Templars which - depending on how many colossi you have left - either make his vikings useless because they can't really engage High Templars or they can cover your Colossi with Psi Storms against Vikings.

Alternatively, you can go for very fast High Templars and use a Zealot/Archon/HT composition though i wouldn't recommend it at your level. You really need to know how to engage when you use it, one bad engagement and you lose instantly since High Templars need forever to get energy for Psi Storm after they get warped in.

In general, i would recommend sticking to Robo units (Immortal/Colossi) as the backbone of your Warpgate army since High Templars can be really distracting from what you really should be doing, especially in the lower levels. You'll try to hit Psi Storms instead of macroing.

Comment: @dbmerlin this is definitely the best answer for the question with many answers because its situational. Good Job!